# Awkwardness creating a property in an object with a key called __proto__

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at this code and copying it into Chrome's console.

```js
let __proto__ = {color: "red"};
let o1 = {__proto__};

const newO1 = Object.create(o1);
```

1. I understand `let o1 = {__proto__};` uses 'shorthand property name' technique.

When I log `o1` I expected:

```js
{
__proto__: {//data property
  color: "red",
  __proto__: Object.prototype //the accessor object
  }
}
```

What I get is:
[image]

---

2. When logging `new01`, I expected:

```js
{
__proto__: 
  __proto__: {color: "red"},
  __proto__: Object.prototype
}
```

I get:
[image]

I'm quite stuck what going on when we make our own property called `__proto__`!

Comment: There are no rules. Console implementations follow no agreed-upon spec. They're designed to help programmers by behaving in ways that the designers hope will be useful.

Comment: @Pointy I think I can get past point 1 because it does have `{__proto__: {...}` at the top. However in point 2 I don't know what is going on here

Comment: @Pointy `__proto__` seems to be they key of `{__proto__. Object.prototype}` and I'm not sure how we got here

Comment: Well setting the prototype of an object is not really the best idea, and doing it by setting `__proto__` is deprecated anyway. `Object.setPrototypeOf()` is preferred, but cases where it's really justified are rare and may be indicative of a design mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for below:

```js
const o1 = {};
Object.defineProperty(o1, 'color', {
  get: () => 'red',
});
const newo1 = Object.create(o1);
console.log(newo1.color);
```